# Understanding the essential range

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

A problem on the essential range has been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754853/real-analysis-folland-problem-6-1-11-lp-spaces). In the solution, it's been stated that if $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$ is finite, then it trivially follows that the essential range $R_f$ is bounded. It's presumably easy but, unfortunately I can't see why. here's the precise definition of the essential range of $f$:
$$R_f :=\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \text{for all}\ \varepsilon > 0: \mu(\{x : |f(x) - z| < \varepsilon\}) > 0\right\}$$

I know that if  $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} < \infty$ then $\lvert f \rvert \leq \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$ a.e but I can't see why this immidiately implies that $R_f$ is bounded, as the definition of $R_f$ looks formidable and I can't seem to parse it. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I know $R_f$ is closed. If it's proved that $R_f$ is bounded then by the Heine-Borel Theorem it follows that $R_f$ is compact. But how  does this imply that $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} = \max \{ \lvert z \rvert : z\in R_f \}$?

Comment: That $R_f$ is bounded is the same as saying there's a number $r\ge0$ such that $\forall z\in R_f\,\,\, |z| \le r.$ Can you guess what that number might be if $\|f\|_\infty$ is finite? $\qquad$

Comment: I can guess it's $ r = \lVert f \rVert_{\infty} $ but I can't seem to prove it using the definition of $R_f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the formal proof you want: let $|z|>||f||_\infty$ and let $0<\epsilon <|z|-|f||_\infty$. Consider the open ball $B(z,\epsilon)$ with center z and radius $\epsilon$. If $f(x) \in B(z,\epsilon)$ then $|f(x)| \geq |z| -|f(x)-z|>|z|-\epsilon>||f||_\infty$. By definition of $||f||_\infty$ this implies that $\mu (f^{-1} (B,x,\epsilon))=0$ which implies that z is not in $R_f$. In other words $|z|\leq ||f||_\infty$ whenever $z \in R_f$. As you have observed this implies that $R_f$ is compact. So $max\{|z|:z\in R_f\}$ is attained and if this maximum is less than $||f||_\infty$ we see that $|f| \leq r$ a.e. for some $r<||f||_\infty$ contradicting the definition of $||f||_\infty$.

Some details for the last part: suppose $max\{|z|:z\in R_f\}<||f||_\infty$. Consider $A=\{z: max\{|z|:z\in R_f\}<|z|<||f||_\infty$. This annulus can be written as a countable union of open balls. Also $\mu(f^{-1}(A))>0$ (by definition of $||f||_\infty$). Hence there is an open ball $B(z_0,r)$ in $A$ such that $\mu (f^{-1}(B(z_0,r)))>0$. But then $z_0 \in R_f$ and this contradicts the fact that  $|z_0| >max\{|z|:z\in R_f\}$.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks! Oh and, happy retirement :))

Comment: Could you explain why if $\max\{|z|:z\in R_{f}\}$ is less than $\|f\|_{\infty}$ then $|f|\leq r$ a.e. for some $r<\|f\|_{\infty}$? I cannot find an explicit reason but I am sure it's true.

Comment: @richarddedekind Thanks for your comment. Indeed, the last part needed some details. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I don't see why we can say $z_0\in\mathcal{R}_f$, for if that we were true we would have to show $\mu(f^{-1}(B(z_0,\delta)))>0$ for ALL choices of $\delta>0$. However, the argument only shows it for some $r>0$.  Isn't it possible that for some $r'<r$ we could have $\mu(f^{-1}(B(z_0,r')))=0$?